# EF Core PostgreSQL running parameterized stored procedures

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am migrating a project that I developed with EF Core 7 to Postgresql in a SQL Server environment.

But I have a problem

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.iletisim_sms_organkullanicigrupharicitelefon(
    IN kullanicibilgisi integer,
    IN smstanimbilgisi integer,
    IN organtanimlari text,
    IN kullanicitanimlari text,
    IN gruptanimlari text,
    IN haricitelefontanimlari text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

I set the stored procedure build according to pl pgsql.

I am using the `ExecuteSqlRaw` method because I have developed my EF Core application with a generic repository.

```
public void SorguCalistir(string Sorgu, params object[] Deger)
{
    using (var Baglam = new Context())
    {
        Baglam.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(Sorgu, Deger);
    }
}
```

The method here takes the first query and then the parameter. I was previously creating parameter values and parameter names with `SqlParameter` in SQL Server, and adding them after the query,
but now I can't do this with call in postgresql

```
call iletisim_sms_organkullanicigrupharicitelefon ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
```

Here probably the query comes in postgresql but it can't position the parameters.

How can I solve this problem and run a stored procedure with parameters?